# Linearly independent for cosinus

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\{\lambda_k\}_{k=1}^n$ be a sequence of real numbers. How can I show that $\{\cos \lambda_k x\}_{k=1}^n$ are linearly independent in $C(-1,1)$ where $\lambda_k \neq \lambda_j ~~\forall~~ k\neq j$?

Comment: Source of problem? Reason for interest? Evidence of any effort on your part?

Comment: The statement is trivially false if one allow $\lambda_j = -\lambda_k$ for some $j \ne k$.

Comment: yes, you right but equality here means equality in norm (absolute)

Comment: @mahdieh +1 For Great Question

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** The key word is **Vandermonde** matrix (or determinant).

We will need the assume the $\lambda_i$ are non-negative, since $\cos(-x)=\cos x$.

Consider the functions, evaluated at $0$, their fourth derivatives, evaluated at $0$, their eighth derivatives, evaluated at $0$, their twelfth derivatives at $0$, and so on up to the $4(n-1)$-th derivatives at $0$. Form this variant of the Wronskian at $0$. This turns out to be a matrix of the Vandermonde type, and therefore it has non-zero determinant, that is, full rank.

But if there were a linear dependence relation between the $\cos(\lambda_i x)$, the determinant above would be $0$.

Comment: whats the role of c(-1,1)?

Comment: It plays no important role. If we are going to discuss the linear dependence/independence of certain functions, they must live in a specified vector space. The space of continuously differentiable functions on $(-1,1)$ is such a space. We could also have worked in the space of **all** functions defined on $(-1,1)$, or defined everywhere. There are many other vector spaces of functions we could have used as the underlying vector space, as long as these functions include our cosines and their linear combinations.